# Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null on HttpGet Android

Tags: android, service, get

I'm trying to pass parameters within a encoded GET url to a webService, but I only get the error Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null

on line:

```
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

code:

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URLEncoder.encode(url));


            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

encoded url being:

```
http://10.247.54.104/SIP.Servico.Comum/api/DataBase/ExecutarQuery?sql=SELECT+
A.COD_IDENT_UNMET+UM,+A.COD_LOCAL_UNMET+LOCAL,+
decode(A.COD_SITUA_UNMET,+'D','FATURADA',+'X',+'DESATIVADA',+'P',+'EM+PROCESSAMENTO',+'F',+'PEND.+FECHAMENTO',+'B',+'EM+PREPARACAO',+'R',+'RESERVADA',+'T',+'PENDENTE',+'Q',+'EM+RECEBIMENTO',+'I',+'DEVOLVIDA+LTQ',+'S',+'SUCATADA',+'+',+'PROGRAMAVEL',+A.COD_SITUA_UNMET)+SITUA,+B.COD_EQPMT_PRODC_DEPOSITO+DEPOSITO+
FROM+ACECPGER_SIL.UNIDADES_METALICAS@LK_QO40_QO30_DBA+A,+ACECPGER_SIL.HISTORICOS_UM@LK_QO40_QO30_DBA+B+WHERE+A.COD_IDENT_UNMET+=+B.COD_IDENT_UNMET+AND+A.SEQ_OPERA_UNMET+=+B.SEQ_OPERA_UNMET+AND+A.COD_SITUA_UNMET+IN+('QQ',+'A',+'B',+'C',+'E',+'F',+'G',+'H',+'I',+'J','L',+'M',+'N',+'P',+'Q',+'R',+'T',+'S')+AND+SUBSTR(A.COD_IDENT_UNMET,+7,+1)+<>+'T'+AND+A.COD_IDENT_UNMET+LIKE'FFF%'+'%'+ORDER+BY+A.COD_IDENT_UNMET
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update yourself man. Use Retrofit or some other modern lib. What is this even :D

Comment: I suggest to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) Just what Vucko says. Its Easy and fast networking

Comment: Is there a reliable tutorial link that you can give me? All the ones I tried were outdated :(